# First name & Last name separated or together in a database, which is better?

Tags: database, database-design

What would be better to create on the database on the table users?

- id
- username
- password
- **fullName**

or

- id
- username
- password
- **firstName**
- **lastName**

I've been trying to find this but the only thing I find about this is "how names are different in different countries".
Which is more usefull and better to put in a database?

Comment: Why would you _not_ separate them?

Comment: It depends. If you explicitly need `firstName` and `lastName` separated (ex. to group by last names), then merging the two violates first normal form. But a `fullName` column is more flexible if you just need the name and don't intend to do any processing on it.

Comment: Ultimately, you should use both.  Better for sorting.  Less code later.  More information.  And, one extra column doesn't take up a lot of space.

Comment: Some people only have one name, like SO user http://stackoverflow.com/users/102580/sai . Many Latinos have two surnames, and it can be rude to address them using both, and which one depends on the country.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Personally, I believe it is a lot easier to concatenate first and last names together than it is to parse a string that may have one or more of these. 
The result would be the same, but more organized.